# weblogic server 12.2.1.3.0 config.cmd did not work on windows 10

Tags: domain, configure, oracle-12c

I am trying to setup weblogic server 12.2.1.3.0 on windows 10. I run fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls.jar successfully. But when I try to create domain using config.cmd file, configuration wizard wasn't opened. I repatedly did deinstall/unstall weblogic but problem wasn't solved.

Java version : 1.8.0_66

Thanks for your help from now on..

Note: This problem didn't exist when I first install weblogic server. When I deinstalled first installation (I dont know why I did this), problems started like above.

**UPDATE**: this problem still exists but I learned that domains are also created by WLST scripts. Using below commands in order:
1. cd WLS_HOME\OracleCommon\common\bin\
2. setWLSTEnv.cmd
3. wlst.cmd

WLST scripting Shell is opened in command prompt. Then we copy the contents of 
**WLS_HOME\inventory\Templates\wlserver\common\templates\scripts\wlst\basicWLSDomain.py** file. Beore doing that please enterthe admin password in the file.